# siunitx custom file with subfiles

Tags: input, include, subfiles

I recently decided to divide my thesis into several nested files as it follows:

% Main.tex

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\include{units}
\begin{document}
\subfile{pre_textual} % ToC, lists, etc.
\subfile{textual}
\subfile{pos_textual}
\end{document}
```

The units file is in the same directory as main.tex.
And the usual subfile:

%textual.tex

```
\documentclass[../../main.tex]{subfiles} %this is because it's nested
\begin{document}
\subfile{chapter1}
\subfile{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

%chapter1.tex

```
\documentclass[../../../main.tex]{subfiles} %this is because it's nested
\begin{document}
text yada \si{\CustomUnit}
\end{document}
```

Problem is, when I compile the subfile (textual or chapter) it doesn't find the units file.
If I add the full path to the `units.tex` I get the error

```
Can't write to the file
```

**Edit**:

My units.tex file looks like this

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\lix}{g/cm^2\day}
\DeclareSIUnit{\molp}{\mole\%}
\DeclareSIUnit{\taxaresf}{\degreeCelsius/\minute}
```

except it has more lines, and enough units to make me create a separated file.

Comment: Does this has something to do with `siunitx`? What does this `unit.tex` file look like? Why don't you put your preamble in the main document? Does your solution below work with just `\input{unitx}` (which would be the typical approach here)? Have you checked the manual of `subfiles` on any caveats with `\include`?

Comment: @ LaRiFaRi, I am not sure if it's related to `siunitx`, but doesn't seem so. The preamble is in the main document. My solution works for this case, haven't tested with others because things like glossaries are loaded with `\loadglsentries` so `siunitx` was the only `include` command I had.
And... no, I didn't read the manual but now I did and it states clearly 

>The preamble of the main file can \input (not \include nor \subfile) files (v.g. files with definitions and shorthand-commands), and the subfiles will too.

So thanks for bumping, will edit my answer.

Comment: Great to hear that. Thanks for the update. Please accept your answer in order to close here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to add the full path using `input` instead of include.
If you use simply input without full path won't work either.

So I endup with this:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}           
\input{D:/OneDrive/Documents/Thesis_latex/units}
```

This happens because the [`subfiles`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles?lang=en) package does not like `\include`s in the preamble.

Section 2.3 of the manual:

> The preamble of the main file can \input (not \include nor \subfile) files (v.g. files with definitions and shorthand-commands), and the subfiles will
>   too.